# ADO recordset not populated by ADO command execute method

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I am doing some clean up to protect from SQL injection attacks happening in a older internal website that uses ASP. Here's the gist of it all in code...

Database connection is setup in a separate asp file named connect.asp

```
<%
on error resume next

Set DB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DB.CommandTimeout = 180
DB.ConnectionTimeout = 180

connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx;"

DB.Open connStr

' Check DB connection and go to Error Handler is error exists
if DB.state=0 then
    Response.Write "<p>Cannot connect to database.</p>"
    TrapError Err.description
    Response.end
end if
%>
```

This works and the db connections is opened.

I have a file named DBFunctions.asp that I use to sort of map functions to stored procedures and their parameters. I  am trying to use the function below to return a ADO recordset to another asp front end page.

```
Function GetFacilityByFID(fid)
    set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = DB
    cmd.CommandText = "GetFacilityByFID"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@FID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20)
    cmd("@FID") = fid
    Set rs =  cmd.Execute
    Set GetFacilityByFID = rs       
End Function
```

Here is the code from the calling front end asp page, facDetail.asp

```
<%

Dim FID, FCBI, Error
FID = Request("FID")
FCBI = Request("FCBI") 

' Check DB connection and go to Error Handler is error exists
if DB.state=0 then
    Response.Write "<p>Cannot connect to database.</p>"
    TrapError Err.description
    Response.end
else
    if FID then
        Set RS = GetFacilityByFID(FID) 
    elseif FCBI then
        Set RS = GetFacilityByFCBI(FCBI)
    end if

    if RS.EOF then
        Response.Write "<BR><p class=alert>No record found</p>"
        response.End
    end if
end if
%>
```

The calling page is displaying that there are no records returned

[image]

but the stored procedure works when executed in SSMS.

**Updated code**

Here's the SQL Code for the GetFacilityByFID stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFacilityByFID] 
    @FID varchar(20) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT [FAC_CBI_NBR]
  ,[FAC_ID]
  ,[FAC_TYPE]
  ,[FAC_SUBTYPE]
  ,[FAC_REGION]
  ,[FAC_COST_CENTER]
  ,[FAC_SUPPLY_CODE]
  ,[FAC_UPLINE]
  ,[FAC_SERVICE]
  ,[FAC_LOCATION_NAME]
  ,[FAC_LOCAL_ADDR1]
  ,[FAC_LOCAL_ADDR2]
  ,[FAC_LOCAL_CITY]
  ,[FAC_LOCAL_STATE]
  ,[FAC_LOCAL_ZIP]
  ,[FAC_MAIL_ADDR1]
  ,[FAC_MAIL_ADDR2]
  ,[FAC_MAIL_CITY]
  ,[FAC_MAIL_STATE]
  ,[FAC_MAIL_ZIP]
  ,[FAC_COUNTRY]
  ,[FAC_PHONE]
  ,[FAC_FAX]
  ,[FAC_MANAGER]
  ,[FAC_CONTACT]
  ,[FAC_CONTACT_PHONE]
  ,[FAC_CONTACT_EXT]
  ,[FAC_CONTACT_EMAIL]
  ,[FAC_COMMENTS]
  ,[FAC_CHANGED_BY]
  ,[FAC_LAST_UPDATE]
  ,[FAC_MAILOUT]
  ,[FAC_CONTRACTION]
  ,[FAC_PROPERTY_CODE]
  ,[FAC_ATTN_TO]
FROM [cbid].[dbo].[FACILITY] 
WHERE [FAC_ID]=@FID
END

GO
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong? I have been looking at this too long and have grown frustrated with it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Current Status of issue: getting the following from the ADO provider

> Error Number: -2147217904 Error Desc: Procedure or function 'GetFacilityByFID' expects parameter '@FID', which was not supplied. Error Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

Comment: I'm not surprised it's a real mess, best advice I can give is comment out `On Error Resume Next` see what errors you are actually getting and take it from there.

Comment: I'll remove the On Error resume next line and see what I get.

Comment: It's definitely the first thing you should do in this situation as any errors are just getting hidden by the statement. The way `On Error Resume Next` works is when it encounters a statement that errors it records the error to the `Err` object and moves on to the next statement, this can happen continuously making finding the original error a problem.

Comment: Implemented some custom error trapping on each page and found the following happening.
  
Error Number: -2147217904 

Error Desc: Procedure or function 'GetFacilityByFID' expects parameter '@FID', which was not supplied. 

Error Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

Comment: Also don't use *"custom error trapping"* i.e `On Error Resume Next` while debugging, as I've already suggested comment out the `On Error Resume Next` line and see what the initial error is. Custom error trapping while it may trap an error it won't necessarily trap the initial error, which could have a domino effect.

Comment: It's also not a good idea to not declare local variables i.e in the `GetFacilityByFID()` function you make references to `rs` and `cmd` but do not declare them in the local scope before using `Dim rs, cmd`.

Comment: But now I have to figure out where I'm getting a Type Mismatch. New question/post.

Comment: Why does that need a new question? Just update this one with the error you are now receiving.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the size.

From [CreateParameter Method (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If you specify a variable-length data type in the *Type* argument, you
>   must either pass a *Size* argument or set the
>   [Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681445(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   property of the **Parameter** object before appending it to the
>   **Parameters** collection; otherwise, an error occurs.

`cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@FID", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(fid))`

Comment: @MattPedigo You still get the same error or something else? It's important to know the error to diagnose the problem. Also, is it possible to show your procedure's (GetFacilityByFID) create script?

Comment: Still same error...
Error Number: -2147217904 Error Desc: Procedure or function 'GetFacilityByFID' expects parameter '@FID', which was not supplied. Error Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server.

I'll post the sql stored procedure code.

Comment: @MattPedigo After seeing the script all I can say is that the `fid` (GetFacilityByFID parameter) is empty or null. check its value by printing `IsNull(fid)`, `IsEmpty(fid)` and `Len(fid)>0`. other than that everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Before going any further, the first thing is to confirm if your stored procedure GetFacilityByFID actually returns a Recordset? Most likely it does not. If it only return a single string value, you should modify `Function GetFacilityByFID(fid)` to something like below:

```
Function GetFacilityByFID(fid)
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = DB
    cmd.CommandText = "GetFacilityByFID"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@returnVal", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 255, "")
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@FID", adVarChar, adParamInput)
    cmd("@FID") = fid
    cmd.Execute
    GetFacilityByFID = cmd("@returnVal")
End Function
```

Comment: The stored procedure returns all fields from a table named Facility and works when tested manually in SSMS.

Comment: @MattPedigo You can't pass an `adVarchar` typed parameter without specifying its size which I explained in my answer. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes I have tried your suggestion. Thanks but it didn't help. I haven't updated the code example to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the function using some of the examples I found and some of LankyMart's suggestions. Thanks everyone for your help.

Here's the working code...

```
 Function GetFacilityByFID(fid)

    Set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = DB
    cmd.CommandText = "GetFacilityByFID"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 900
    set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@FID",adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, fid)
    cmd.Parameters.Append prm
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    Set GetFacilityByFID = rs

On Error GoTo 0   
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you're setting the parameters looks no right, try this instead:

```
Dim param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@FID", adVarChar, adParamInput)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
param.Value = fid
```

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms675860(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo Pontual but no luck or changes. I had tried this way in the beginning but had found the current to be abbreviated version and essential the same.

Comment: The way the parameter is set is perfectly acceptable. If it wasn't you would likely get an error unless `On Error Resume Next` was set. You really don't need all that extra fluff to set a parameter.